# actionscript 3, play sound instance through XML

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, audio

I've set up my program to dynamically access instances by XML.

eg: `MovieClip(getChildByName(XML_file.child(event.target.name).combine.toString()).visible=true);` ... etc

Now I want to play some sound I've already declared with the same method

Basically every Movieclip have its own XML element with some other tags

```
<MC_1>
   <generate>MC_2</generate>
   <sound>Sound1</sound>
...etc
</MC_1>
```

---

EDIT

Im building a simple point and click graphic adventure game (like Monkey Island, Grim Fandango, Broken Sword etc)

I have an external xml file (puzzle_xml) every element correspond to a MovieClip (an object in game), every element have tag such as (id, generate, description, talk)etc.

Im trying to write a code that allows me to change the way object interact by just editing the xml file so i have to dynamically access the MovieClips

```
MovieClip(MovieClip(getChildByName(puzzle_xml.child(puzzle_xml.child(event.target.name).generate).destination.toString())).getChildByName(puzzle_xml.child(event.target.name).generate.toString())).visible=true;
```

The code above works fine (it made became visible the MovieClip that should become visible after a drag and drop of a MovieClip on another)

Now I need a sound to be played (the character comments), dynamically as always.

```
this[puzzle_xml.child(targetItem).talk].play();
```

Finally found the solution, the nested "getChildByName" have not worked.

With this code, when I drag an object on another if they suppesed to be compatible (xml) a new object is created (visible) and a sound is played. Using a single variable (targetItem that is event.target.item)

Comment: Your question is unclear, could you explain more your problem ?

Comment: I actually access all my MovieClip instances by XML tag, I want to access also my sound instances the same way.

Comment: That example code you posted would not work. Post a working example. Also, what *exactly* is the text `Sound1` supposed to relate to?

Comment: Edited the original post, hope this is more clear